# SslStream Escaping UTF-8 URL Encoding Above %7F (Multi-byte)?

Tags: .net

I am trying to send special characters via an SslStream and StreamWriter that makes a URL GET request like so:

```
var req = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Get, m_client.BaseAddress );
m_sessionClient.AddSessionInfoTo( req );

var uri = req.RequestUri;


var client = new TcpClient( uri.Host, uri.Port );

Stream stream = client.GetStream();

var ssl = new SslStream( stream );


ssl.AuthenticateAsClient( uri.Host );



var writer = new StreamWriter(
                ssl,
                new UTF8Encoding( encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false )
);


await writer.WriteAsync( $"{req.Method.Method} " );


await writer.FlushAsync();

var path = "/echo/%C9%52";
var rawPathAndQuery = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( path );
await ssl.WriteAsync( rawPathAndQuery, 0, rawPathAndQuery.Length );



await writer.WriteAsync( " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " );

await writer.WriteAsync( req.RequestUri.Host );

await writer.WriteAsync( "\r\n" );


await writer.WriteAsync( "\r\n" );

await writer.FlushAsync();
```

This code should send ÉR, but from Wireshark I can see that writer.FlushAsync is making this request: GET /echo/%25C9R HTTP/1.1

It seems like ssl.WriteAsync is escaping the % character for some reason? This only occurs for multi-byte UTF8, AKA values starting from %80. Why might this be happening and how can I prevent it from escaping the % sign?

I was expecting the request made would be ÉR, not %25C9R

I would also like to clarify that I am looking for an explanation, not necessarily a fix. I can find no documentation in StreamWriter or SslStream that would indicate any escaping of UTF8, in addition visiting

echo/%C9 in the browser works perfectly fine. I want to know what is causing this behaviour.

Comment: That's what you asked it to do `var path = "/echo/%C9%52";`. The `SslStream` doesn't do anything except deal with bytes, no encoding is done. You are doing `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` manually for some reason, rather than using the `writer` but that also will not make any changes. If you wanted the `path` different then change it. Side note: you are missing a bunch of `using` blocks here. Also why are you doing this manually, why not just use `HttpClient`?

Answer (score 0):

Update: This seems to be a YARP problem, which is also escaping %2F creating implications for encoded paths.

See
https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy/issues/1777

https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy/issues/1419

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11544